# JavaScript instance functions versus prototype functions

Tags: javascript, syntax, prototype-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

My understanding of the different kinds of JavaScript functions are as follows:

```
function MyObj() {
    this.propOne = true;
    this.publicInstanceFunc = function() {
        if (propOne)
            return 'public instance function';
    }
    function privateFunc() {
        return 'private function only visible inside this constructor';
    }
}

MyObj.prototype.protoFunc = function() {
    if (this.propOne)
        return 'prototype function shared amongst all instances of MyObj';
}
```

1. Are these correct?
2. In what cases should one put functions on the prototype (e.g. `protoFunc`) vs. in the constructor (e.g. `publicInstanceFunc`)?
3. Is using `this` the correct way to access properties inside prototype functions?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can actually add another level of privilege via wrapping the whole thing in a self-executing function:

```
var MyObj = (function() { // scoping
    var privateSharedVar = 'foo';

    function privateSharedFunction() {
        // has access to privateSharedVar
        // may also access publicSharedVar via explicit MyObj.prototype
        // can't be called via this
    }

    function MyObj() { // constructor
        var privateInstanceVar = 'bar';
        this.publicInstanceVar = 'baz';

        function privateInstanceFunction() {
            // has access to all vars
            // can't be called via this
        };

        this.publicInstanceMethod = function() {
            // has access to all vars
            // also known as a privileged method
        };
    }

    MyObj.prototype.publicSharedVar = 'quux';

    MyObj.prototype.publicSharedMethod = function() {
        // has access to shared and public vars
        // canonical way for method creation:
        // try to use this as much as possible
    };

    return MyObj;
})();
```

Only 'public' properties can be accessed from outside via `this`.

For performance reasons, you should avoid what I called 'instance' methods: For each of these, a new function object must be created for each `MyObject` instance, whereas there's only a single function object per 'shared' method.

Comment: sorry to resurrect this question/answer, but does wrapping that outer function in parens do anything special? e.g. how is (function(){ })(); different from function(){}();

Comment: @Matt: the outer parens force the function literal to be interpreted as an expression instead of a statement; they are unnecessary in this case because the assignment already forces this interpretation, but without it, you should get a syntax error if you omit the parens

Comment: Thanks for this excellent example, Christoph. What would you do if you wanted to define another object within that namespace? For example, if MyObj contained an array of MyObj2's. Would you define that as part of the immediately-invoked function so that it's within MyObj's namespace?

Comment: A smaller question: Shouldn't the return be `return new MyObj();`? That's what I had to do to make it work, but want to make I didn't break well-formed code.

Comment: @scader: as-is, the outer var `MyObj` will hold the constructor function and can be used as such (ie to instantiate object via `new MyObj()`); if you returned `new MyObj()` instead, the outer var would hold only that particular instance

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, and also why you capitalized the 'M' in the namespace. I was thinking it was designed to return an instance, not a definition because I didn't fully read your last paragraph. Are you able to answer my other question? (Maybe I should create a new question for it and link to this question as reference?)

Comment: @scader: yes, you would define `MyObj2` within the scoping function; however, if you want to make `MyObj2` public as well (ie invokable from the outside), returning the `MyObj` constructor only won't be flexible enough; in that case, you'd probably return a namespace object instead (or require one to be passed as argument to the self-executing function)

Comment: **Immediately invoked** function is a better term than ***self-executable** function.

Answer (score 4):

> Are these correct?

Err. Well, it depends what you want to do. There is no one accepted canonical model for implementing class/instance-style inheritance in JavaScript.

But this:

> ```
>     if (propOne)
> ```

Is probably a mistake, in that `this.propOne` is a property of the owner object, whereas `propOne` by itself is a variable that hasn't been declared (this defaults to a global variable, but is usually a wrongness).

> In what cases should one put functions on the prototype (e.g. protoFunc) vs. in the constructor (e.g. publicInstanceFunc)?

A function set on the prototype is the same function shared amongst all objects. The only way it can work out what instance it belongs to is by reading ‘this’ when it is called.

A function set on ‘this’ in the constructor is a new function for every instance of the `MyObj`. You can possibly use this as an alternative way to bind to the owner object based on closures instead of ‘this’, which can save writing out function-binding stuff. It's a different style of object-orientation which normally you wouldn't mix with the this-based style.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes your code is right.

2) I use functions defined within the constructor function when I want to access other members defined privately inside the scope of the constructor function itself, for example, when you want to create [privileged methods](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html).

Public functions defined on the constructor function, are more computationally expensive than adding a simple function to the object prototype, but they also give you much more flexibility.

3) Yes, if the property is public you are able to access it by using the `this` keyword inside of a prototype extended function, since `this` refers to the instance of your object.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second point, you extend the prototype so that all the already created objects get the new method.

Also, allows you to add methods to the built-in objects (like adding `trim()` to `string`).