# Is there a memory performance benefit of assigning a function to the prototype in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, prototype

I read that adding functions to an object will chew up more memory then adding functions to the prototype of the object.

```
function Obj() {
    this.M = function() { // do something };
}

var o = new Obj();
```

The idea was that for every construction of Obj, a new function is created and applied to Obj, thus increasing memory use. For 1000 instances of Obj, 1000 functions will need to be created.

```
function Obj() {

}
Obj.prototype.M = function() { // do something };

var o = new Obj();
```

For 1000 instances of Obj, in this case, only the one function is created. Netting a total saving of 999 * sizeof(M) memory.

Is this really the case? If it is, in what category would the following fall under:

```
function Obj() {
    Obj.prototype.M = function() { // do something };
}
var o = new Obj();
```

My instincts tell me that for every construction of Obj in this example, the prototype will be assigned each time. I'm not sure what to think of memory use in this case, since assigning the same function to the prototype would just replace the function instead of creating N copies of it for N instances.

I have just started using this method to encapsulate creation of the member functions, but want to be sure that I'm not doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @bergi I'm not sure that marking this as a duplicate makes sense, considering it was asked 2 years before the linked duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I treat [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572) as the canonical Q&A, so age doesn't matter. Users who found your question because of the title (*Is there a memory performance benefit?*) should be redirected there. However, next to "*Is this really the case?*", your actual question seems to be "*I want to be sure that I'm not doing the wrong thing*" about that third pattern, which is actually a …

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning prototype methods *inside* the constructor function - why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28255957/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function Obj() {
>     Obj.prototype.M = function() { // do something };
> }
> var o = new Obj();
> ```

Well, as you surmised, that'll create an anonymous function and assign it to the prototype during the construction of a new object. It's just pointless, [and slightly slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80802/does-use-of-anonymous-functions-affect-performance)... unless you actually capture something like an argument to the constructor in that closure, in which case it's also *weird* - because whatever the current `M()` happens to be, it'll still be shared with *all* instances of Obj:

```
function Obj(name)
{
  Obj.prototype.M = function() { alert("Hello, " + name); }
}

var shog = new Obj("shog");
var josh = new Obj("josh");
  
shog.M(); // alerts, "Hello, josh"
josh.M(); // alerts, "Hello, josh"
```

If you come up with a good use for this, I'd love to hear it...
​

#### See also:

> - [JavaScript instance functions vs. prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441212/javascript-instance-functions-vs-prototype-functions)
> - [Does use of anonymous functions affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80802/does-use-of-anonymous-functions-affect-performance)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been mentioned. You will see moderate performance loss if that closure has a handle on a local variable (like a constructor parameter). Not only would this be weird, as the previous poster mentioned, but it will prevent that referenced variable from even being garbage collected