# Performance and memory of prototype pollution vs dedicated library object

Tags: javascript, performance, oop

Not sure if this is a new question so pls ref to any good source if you have any.

My team is working on a big JS chart project we inherited from the previous developers who made intensive use of built-in objects prototypes for adding reusable code. We have a lot of new utility functions added to Date, Object and other intrinsic objects so I guess they went this way 'cause altering prototypes provides a bit more intuitive API.

On the other hand our component suffers from performance/memory gotchas and we apply all the possible optimizations and best practices. I can't find one regarding API design. I'm trying to figure out whether it's better to seed **built-in objects' prototypes** with library code instead of combining them in dedicated objects via somewhat namespace pattern.

The question is which design is better? And will one of them gain performance and/or memory over another?

```
Date.prototype.my_custom_function = new function (...) {...};
var period = new Date();
period.my_custom_function();
```

vs

```
DateLib.my_custom_function // defined in a DateLib function
var period = new Date();
DateLib.my_custom_function(period);
```

Thanks, guys, any help is appreciated!

**EDIt**:
The main problem is that our component ended up being an awkward JS beast that slows down some mobile devices, especially old ones, such as iPad1 and early Androids... We've done a lot of optimization but I still see several questionable parts. I want to make sure if the built-in prototype pollution is another candidate to look into.
Particularly, the `Date` and `Object` guys are heavily loaded with typical library code. For example, in fact the `my_custom_function` is a big big function and it's not the only additional member that sits on the `Date` prototype at code startup.
The `Object` is loaded even more. Most of the client code doesn't make use of those additional features, it's used on purpose - so we're about to decide whichever way we're better stick with:

- Keep using prototype pollution design
- Refactoring reusable APIs into separate library static objects

to be honest I haven't run perf benchmarks yet, will do once I have time. If someone has outcome/ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think the `Date` example is that bad and I doubt it would affect performance significantly, but I would never touch `Object.prototype`. Would be interested to see some benchmark numbers.

Comment: I don't think this would affect performance. Can you be more specific about the problems you have?

Comment: I would suggest you to read this excellent book that will give you the answer you're looking for, it will explain you a third possibility which is probably the best one: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do

Comment: @Scalpweb: Can you outline that answer and the solution here?

Comment: The books has a whole chapter one of to defined object, so no it's not really possible to explain it in an answer here. Basically, the goal is to avoid building object that need 'new' to be instanciated, and relying on a good understanding of closure and scope to produce safe and optimized JS code. Really, this book made me a better programmer in just a few hours.

Comment: edited the question with more details in case it helps.

Comment: My initial thoughts would be to steer clear of overloaded prototypes, because simple objects that don't make use of those functions are still dragging around that extra info, rather than just using those funcs when they're needed. Not sure if that's actually a performance related issue or not.. but... thought I'd mention it

Comment: @Scalpweb: That book advises to avoid prototypes? Doesn't sound like a good idea. Closures might be safer, but they hardly produce "optimized code". Still, that is a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180790/defining-methods-via-prototype-vs-using-this-in-the-constructor-really-a-perfo)…

Comment: @Bergi: before judging it, it would highly suggest for you to ready it. It opened my eyes on some very powerfull JS features.

Comment: @Scalpweb No, it is exactly the opposite, if you want to get any kind of perf you must avoid closures like the plague. And if you think closures give security then may God help you. Consider that book as something where you take a fact from and then the opposite of that will be actually true.

Comment: @Esailija When did I ever said that closures were "giving security" ? I just said that this book gives you a "good understanding of closure and scope to produce safe and optimized JS code". It's actually exactly the opposite. If you don't want to take the time to read that book that's fine, but please don't make me say something I did not say. But taking some hours to learn new stuff is never a bad idea...

Comment: @Scalpweb Ok you said "safe" instead of "secure"... what is the big difference?

Comment: @Esailija I just said that having a better understanding of closure and scope give you the ability to produce better code, because you will know how to use them in the right way. Seriously man, I'm not gonna lose more time on that silly discussion. I'd be happy if, like you, I could presume my knowledge was better than Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Modifying objects you don't own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) is definitely bad idea. The choice here is rather architectural: if you have to store a date persistently, then use a private property of the constructor:

```
function DateLib() {
  this._dateObject = new Date();
}

DateLib.prototype.getDateString = function () {
  return this._dateObject.toDateString()
};

var dateLib = new DateLib();
dateLib.getDateString();
```

If you just want to do some manipulation with a date, create a method:

```
var DateLib = {
  toDateString: function (date) {
    return date.toDateString()
  }
}

DateLib.toDateString(new Date());
```

As it comes to the performance, all approaches [are equally fast](http://jsperf.com/defining-a-method-constructor-vs-object/2) (thanks to Bergi, [alternative test](http://jsperf.com/defining-a-method-constructor-vs-object/4) by Esailija).

[image]

*Note: this is not browser comparison test. Tests were performed on a different machines, so only method-vs-method performance should be analysed here.*

Comment: That jsperf test is not representative for anything.

Comment: @Bergi totally agree. But the question is about a performance and this test is the only one I came up with. Could you create a better one?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to test the OP's exact requirements, but you should at least do something like [this test](http://jsperf.com/defining-a-method-constructor-vs-object/2) where you are testing the execution of your methods, not their creation.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I don't think implementation details will affect the result of the test, the proportion must stay the same.
From design perspectives, yes, I'm agree too - overloading built-in types' prototypes doesn't sound the best solution.

Comment: This benchmark is completely broken, you are doing allocation and system calls in the timed sections which eclipses any possible differences. No wonder nobody gets to even 1MOPS. http://jsperf.com/defining-a-method-constructor-vs-object/4 This has some overhead to get rid of firefox dead code elimination but it shows a difference between the methods. Wrapper and extension should be almost equal where as "static" should be noticeably slower (5%-10%), the jsperf still doesn't show that so these should probably be extracted into functions.

Comment: @Esailija thanks for putting your effort in this, I'll add your test to the answer. But there is still no significant performance difference between the methods.

Comment: @AsyncMind no it doesn't. Let's say you are comparing A to B, A executes in 2 nanoseconds but B executes in 1 nanoseconds I.E. B is twice as fast. Then you add an operation that takes 0.1 milliseconds to both tests. After running for 1 second, you get 99999op/s vs 99998op/s. Which looks like equal even though there was a 100% difference because the expensive operation completely eclipsed any differences.

Comment: @Esailija, thanks. we have that expensive operation so it looks there gonna be no notable performance gain from moving it under a separate library (there are loops but not as big as in the examples). The design consideration is the only motivator for this question, though.