# Javascript prototype handling self and constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Im trying to understand javascript prototyping principles and cant get some basic things to work.
One thing that im trying to achieve is, to create a base object, that handles constructor input, and sets values based on that input, or default values if no constructor parameter is given.

Also, i cant quite figure out how to store this this in a variable so that it would point to correct instance of the object( parent object perhaps )

Below are 2 versions which i have tried to create basic inheritance. ( first one ive seen used before, but it doesnt allow me to handle constructor parameters passed to extended object using its  base object's constructor.
The second version...is something i came up with to enable it, but...i have never seen anyone using prototypes like this and im sure its the wrong way ( since the prototype property is a function instead of an object)

Whats the correct way of solving both of the problems.

```
var Person = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    var _person = this;
    this.first_name = conf.first_name;
    this.last_name = conf.last_name;
    this.greet = function() {
        alert("Hi, im " + this.first_name + " " + this.last_name );
    }
    this.callback_greet = function() {
        alert("Hi, im " + _person.first_name + " " + _person.last_name );
        console.log("this:", this, " _person:", _person );
    }
}

var Student = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    /* id like to pass this conf on to Person constructor */
    this.report = function() {
        alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " is ready to study"  );
    }
}
Student.prototype = new Person();

var Teacher = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    this.teach = function() {
        alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " is ready to teach...maggots"  );
    }
}
Teacher.prototype = new Person();

student  = new Student({first_name: "Mike", last_name: "Stud"});
//student.first_name="Mike";
//student.last_name="Stud";
student.greet();
/* alerts Hi, im Mike Stud */


teacher  = new Teacher();
teacher.first_name="John";
teacher.last_name="Smith";
teacher.teach();
/* alerts John Smith is ready to teach...maggots */
teacher.callback_greet ();
/* both alerted values are undefined */

//_________________________
//_______Version 2  _______
//_________________________

var Person = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    var _person = this;
    this.first_name = conf.first_name;
    this.last_name = conf.last_name;
    this.greet = function() {
        alert("Hi, im " + this.first_name + " " + this.last_name );
    }
    this.callback_greet = function() {
        alert("Hi, im " + _person.first_name + " " + _person.last_name );
        console.log("this:", this, " _person:", _person );
    }
}

var Student = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    this.prototype = Person;
    this.prototype(conf);
    this.report = function() {
        alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " is ready to study"  );
    }
}

var Teacher = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    this.prototype = Person;
    this.prototype(conf);
    this.teach = function() {
        alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " is ready to teach...maggots"  );
    }
}

var Principal = function(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    this.prototype = Teacher;
    this.prototype(conf);
    this.dicipline_teachers = function() {
        alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " thy all mighty principal is watching you"  );
    }
}

student  = new Student({first_name: "Mike", last_name: "Stud"});
student.greet();
/* alerts Hi, im Mike Stud */

teacher  = new Teacher({first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith"});
teacher.teach();
/* alerts John Smith is ready to teach...maggots */

principal  = new Principal({first_name: "David", last_name: "Faustino"});
principal.teach();/* alerts David Faustino is ready to teach...maggots */
principal.dicipline_teachers();/* David Faustino thy all mighty principal is watching you*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your second version is actually… somewhat… **correct**!

What your snippet

> ```
> var Student = function(conf) {
>     this.prototype = Person;
>     this.prototype(conf);
> ```

does here:

1. Have a `Student` instance as `this` when being invoked with `new Student()`
2. Create a property on the instance that contains a function (in this case, the parent constructor), which essentially creates a method on the instance
3. Call that *as a method*. Which means, the `Person` function is invoked with its [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) pointing to the instance that we have here - and then `Person` does its setup on that instance.

This is just what we want. Maybe except for creating the unnessary property. Notice that the name of this property being `prototype` is totally irrelevant for its function, you could have use `myParentConstructor` or so as well.

In the standard JavaScript inheritance, we do a similar thing to that method call - we want to call the parent constructor *on* the current (child) instance so that it does get set up. However, we use the [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for that.

---

Now we also want to use the prototype. In your code, all the methods `greet`, `report`, `teach` and `dicipline_teachers` could be shared amongst the instances, so they can - [and should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572) - go on the [`ConstructorFn.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572). To let all teachers, students, and principals inherit these methods we need to set up a prototype chain (inheritance hierarchy). We [don't want to use `new Person`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) as that would call the constructor and set up things like `first_name` on the prototype object where they would to be shared - but we don't want that. Instead, we use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Alltogether, your code would look like this:

```
function Person(conf) {
    if (!conf) {conf = {};}
    var _person = this;
    this.first_name = conf.first_name;
    this.last_name = conf.last_name;
    this.callback_greet = function() {
        alert("Hi, im " + _person.first_name + " " + _person.last_name );
        console.log("this:", this, " _person:", _person );
    };
}
Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    alert("Hi, im " + this.first_name + " " + this.last_name );
};

function Student(conf) {
    Person.call(this, conf);
}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {constructor:{value:Student}});
Student.prototype.report = function() {
    alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " is ready to study"  );
};

function Teacher(conf) {
    Person.call(this, conf);
}
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {constructor:{value:Teacher}});
Teacher.prototype.teach = function() {
    alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " is ready to teach...maggots"  );
};

function Principal(conf) {
    Teacher.call(this, conf);
}
Principal.prototype = Object.create(Teacher.prototype, {constructor:{value:Principal}});
Principal.prototype.dicipline_teachers = function() {
    alert(  this.first_name + " " + this.last_name + " thy all mighty principal is watching you"  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) It's best to handle setting default values after a proper sanity check on the type(s) of value(s) passed:

```
var Constr = function (conf) {
  if (!!conf && !(conf instanceof Object)) {
    throw new Error('An invalid parameter was passed to Constr.');
  }
  if (!conf) { // Prevent "Can't read property 'name' of undefined." 
    conf = {};
  }
  this.name = conf.name || null; // Set defaults this way.
};
```

(2) You'll want to use `Object.create()` and `Object.apply()` to get this right:

```
var Person = function (param1, param2) {
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
}

Person.prototype.cough = function () {
  // Do stuff.
}

var Student = function (param1, param2, paramN) {
  Person.call(this, param1, param2);
  this.paramN = paramN; // Define a new property on the subclass
}

// Invoke the superclass to have the subclass inherit properties and methods.
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```