# Constructor vs Factory functions

Tags: javascript

I usually prefer to use a functional approach in my JavaScript programming. However, since diving into WebGL, I notice the Three.js library uses constructors and prototypes.

Is there a specific reason to use the `new` keyword when working with 3D Graphics? Better performance? To save memory?

Comment: Prototypes are optimised in js engines. That doesn't mean you have to use `new` of course, you can still use factory functions with them.

Comment: see [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572)

Comment: also, even though the language doesn't require it, you use `new` to make 100% clear for you and everyone reading your code that you are allocating a new object at this point, which you should usually avoid doing in your main loop.