# Setting "this" to the instance, in a callback set during the creation of a prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I have this code:

```
var createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler = function(selectablesArrayGetter) {
    return function() {
        var array = selectablesArrayGetter();
        var desiredState = array.every(function(selectable) { return selectable.selected; }) ? false : true;
        array.forEach(function(selectable) {
            selectable.selected = desiredState;
        });
    };
};
```

Followed by this one:

```
function PromoViewModel() { this.registrations = [...] }   

PromoViewModel.prototype.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler = createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler(function() { return this.registrations; }));
```

I can't manage to set the correct value of this. The "this" value when the function is created points to Window so I can't do .bind(this). I've tried doing .bind(PromoViewModel.prototype) but it lacks all the precious instance fields set inside the constructor.

I know I could simply set this.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler in the constructor function, but I'm trying to separate the methods creation from the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the call `selectablesArrayGetter();` which determines the [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for the callback.

You will need to "pass" the `this` value that the method (i.e. the closure you are returning) is invoked on, using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var array = selectablesArrayGetter.call(this);
```

Comment: This would bind it to the "createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler" function instance, not to the PromoViewModel instance.

Comment: @MichaSchwab: Not sure what you mean. `createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler` isn't a class, and there are no instances. Also, nothing is bound here, it just passes the dynamic `this` value it receives through.

Comment: @dandavis: Notice that `createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler` is not a method of the class. It's just a function that creates the actual method.

Comment: Bergi: You're right. This ensures that the context of the calling class is used, in the createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler method. That works. I think it would be better for the class that passes a callback function to ensure that that function uses the correct context, but I guess that depends.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend defining your `PromoViewModel.prototype.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler` method as follows:

```
PromoViewModel.prototype.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler = function() {
    var _array = this.registrations;
    var desiredState = _array.every(function(selectable) { return selectable.selected; }) ? false : true;
    _array.forEach(function(selectable) {
        selectable.selected = desiredState;
    });
};
```

Comment: Probably OP has multiple handlers though and want to use the closure to abstract

Answer (score 0):

the function that you're passing as callback uses `this`, but doesn't have the `PromoViewModel` context. You can ensure the method has the proper context by binding `this` to a variable.

```
function PromoViewModel()
{
    var me = this;
    this.registrations = [...];
    this.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler = createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler(function() {
        return me.registrations;
    });
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/coegnL5j/9/ also has Bergi's answer in there (commented out) to show that that works just as well.

Comment: Keep in mind [the performance difference to defining it on the prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572) though

Comment: Sure, that's not the point though. You can store the `this` variable in the `prototype.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I did.

In the prototype definition instead of directly associating it to `createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler` function, I actually define a function that returns the `createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler` function.  By doing this, I can define a variable (in this case protoScope) that maps this context when defined.
When doing that, if you put a break-point in the `createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler` function you will see that the `selectablesArrayGetter` value is correct (the acutal registrations array).

```
PromoViewModel.prototype.allEventsSelectedClickedHandler = function (){
    var protoScope = this;
    return createAllAreSelectedClickedHandler(function() { 
        return protoScope.registrations; 
    });
}
```