# Is having a nested function inside a constructor memory inefficient?

Tags: javascript

I've been watching the excellent [Crockford on JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/) videos and got to a point where he argues that using the `new` operator and `<some object>.prototype` can be confusing so he proposes an alternative (as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM&t=3656) around the 1:00:40 mark):

```
function gizmo(id) {
    return {
        id: id,
        toString: function () {
            return "gizmo " + this.id;
        }
    };
}

function hoozit(id) {
    var that = gizmo(id);
    that.test = function (testid) {
        return testid === this.id;
    };
    return that;
}
```

One can indeed argue this looks cleaner and you could just instance *gizmo* and *hoozit* simply by calling `gizmo()` or `hoozit()` respectively. However, based on my understand on how nested functions work, if I had 1000 instances of hoozit at some point, I would have 1000 "copies" of `toString` and 1000 "copies" of `test` as opposed to having just one of each if these functions were added to *gizmo*'s and *hoozit*'s prototypes respectively.

It seems unusual that Crockford would provide such an example as good practice so I was wondering if there's something I'm missing here (such as some hidden JS optimization) or is this simply a case of increasing code quality at the cost of performance?

**Edit:** Since *melpomene* pointed out in the comments that whether or not these nested functions are closures may matter, consider the following example of super methods (same video, [a couple of seconds later](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM&t=3767), slightly simplified):

```
function hoozit(id) {
    var that = gizmo(id);
    var super_toString = that.toString;
    that.test = function (testid) {
        return testid === this.id;
    };
    that.toString = function () {
        return super_toString.apply(that);
    };
    return that;
}
```

In this case, the inner function actually closes over `that` and `super_toString` so I assume it's less likely that some optimization exists.

Comment: I don't see any closures in that code.

Comment: Crockford argues that the benefits of his scheme outweigh the extra memory that it uses (I believe he admits it uses more memory and that it mostly isn't relevant any more on today's devices).  His latest scheme also forgoes use of the prototype if I recall.  FYI, your `gizmo()` function does not have a closure in it.  Your `hoozit()` potentially has a closure, but you don't actually reference the `that` variable from the nested function so it isn't actually providing closure functionality.

Comment: @melpomene Well, this is embarrassing, I haven't actually noticed that the functions don't close over any variables. Still, the functions are nested so I guess my question remains. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: @fstanis I'd expect a JS engine to not create multiple copies if the functions don't close over variables (I know Perl does this).

Comment: From http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html: _The prototype mechanism is used for inheritance. It also conserves memory._ So yes, it is memory inefficiant, according to Crockford.

Comment: @melpomene: Are you suggesting using CoW? Cause even though there any closed variables, the function objects still have to be unique so you can assign properties to them.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Good point. I hadn't considered that.

Comment: I've added a closure example, from the same video, to make the question somewhat more clear.

Comment: related: [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572)

Comment: .prototype is not confusing! Just use it :) Multiple levels of prototype chains is confusing so mixing them into the class is nice before making an instance.