# Performance: prototype private methods

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype

Given the object:

```
object = function ()
{
   var pub = {
      m1: function () {
        m2();
        m3();
      }
   };

   function m2() {
     ...
   }

   function m3() {
     ...
   }

   return pub;
}
```

This object will be instantiate more than one time. Should I add the private functions to the prototype, so they are not copied in every instance?

What could be a limit, perhaps, to a number X of private methods vs number Y of instances.

Comment: How would you implement a private function in a prototype?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'm trading encapsulation by performance.

Comment: How many instances are you planning on creating?

Comment: There is no prototype that you could add to, given that your factory returns plain objects.

Comment: There is no limit. It's just the more members and the more instances you create, the fuller your memory gets.

Comment: @Bergi Actually, I would use `Object.create()`.

Comment: @Bergi Of course there is no limit, life is beautiful :-). What I'm asking if it's worth to declare private methods public (prototype..), to avoid the extra memory.

Comment: @nils It doesn't matter. I'm asking about keeping things private and avoid big usages of memory. It's a general question.

Comment: @user1101: Usually it's not worth it. Untill you have an actual problem, and can identify this as your memory/performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Bergi Agree. I'm just beeing a little curious hehe (aaand trying to follow any pattern if it exists).

Comment: @user1101: If you're just curious, have a look at [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572) (although it's quite possibly outdated)

Answer (score -2):

In OOP Javascript with ES5, your objects can have 3 types of member.

- public
- private
- priviledged

public members are created in the prototype and can be accessed by anyone.

```
var MyCustomClass = function() {
};

MyCustomClass.prototype.myPublicMethod = function() {
};

var myCustomObject = new MyCustomClass();
myCustomObject.myPublicMethod();
```

The private members are created inside the Class constructors and can only be accessed inside the class constructor (you can't access them in the public methods, despite being in the same Class).

```
var MyCustomClass = function() {
    var m_privateMember; //cannot be accessed outside the constructor
};
```

The privileged members are actually public members, but declared inside the constructor, so they can use private members.

```
var MyCustomClass = function() {
    var m_privateMember = 2;

    //Priviledged method (which is a GETTER here)
    this.GetPrivateMember = function() {
        return m_privateMember;
    };
};

var myCustomObject = new MyCustomClass();
console.log(myCustomObject.GetPrivateMember()); //2
```

That allows you to access the private member in your public methods by calling the priviledged GETTER.

Now, about performance. I am currently using this pattern in a project with over 700 objects with, inside them, more than 12 privates members and a lot more priviledged members (~30) because i don't like using public members (have to define members in 2 different places, the constructor and .prototype, so i just define them all in the constructor, and call the 'initialize' methods at the end of the constructor). And I didn't notice any performance issue. Objects are still being instantiated as fast as it can get. I can't guarranty that there is no performance cost, but IMHO, it is not noticeable.

You can also define properties this way :

```
var MyCustomClass = function() {
    var myPrivateMember;

    Object.defineProperty(MyCustomClass.prototype, 'myProperty', {
        get: function() {
            return myPrivateMember; 
        },
        set: function(_param) {
             myPrivateMember = _param;
        }
    });
}

var myObject= new MyCustomClass();
myObject.myProperty = 6;
myObject.myProperty; //6
```

But I don't like it since i prefer calling GetMyProperty(), but its a matter of taste.

You should check Object.definyProperty since i might not have the exact syntax.

---

EDIT for the performance issue.

So I have run some tests in my browser (Chrome 46) and there is no performance hit between private members and public members.

For a ClassA with 12 private members vs a ClassB with 12 public members, I have instantiated 1,000,000 objects of each Class, taking on an average of 10 tests about 250 ms for ClassA and 245 ms for ClassB.

So, feel free to use private members.

Comment: Thank you for your benchmarking! It's makes me wonder if the javascript interpreter "caches" the duplicated private members/functions.