# Factory function vs Constructor functions memory penalies

Tags: javascript, memory, methods, constructor, factory-pattern

I am recently switch to factory functions instead of the constructor function requiring the new operator.
I recently was asked to revert to the constructor "method" based on possible memory penalties of the factory method.

A senior programmer is telling me that when I extend prototypes only one instance of the methods are present in memory and all object instances are pointing to those methods.

Instead with factory functions every instance of the object carry with it a copy of the functions penalising memory.

He explained me this intuitive topic mentioning the existence of a function table and all instances of object created with new() are pointing to it. The same will not be happening with factory based objects.

I am interested in this topic and I would like to receive some clarification to improve my coding skills.

Comment: You can get the best of both worlds by having your factory use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to instantiate objects.

Comment: see also [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572) and linked questions.

Comment: Unless you create tens of thousands of objects, you probably won't notice any difference. Function instances and properties are pretty cheap on memory actually. And if you're really doing anything performance-sensitive, you do have benchmarks in place anyway that let you compare your approaches with hard numbers, right?