# Javascript particles: should I use a factory or an object/prototype pattern?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, factory, particles

Right now I'm using the object/prototype pattern to create simple particles in an animation that is triggered by clicking the "I don't like gray" button on http://hello-mat.com/

I'm wondering if I should use a module pattern (**edit:** a factory! see comments) instead for performance reasons. If I do need the module pattern, I would love to have a better idea on why it would be a good fit in my use case.

Many thanks to anyone willing to explain.

Comment: The module pattern creates single modules, how would you use it for multiple particles? And why do you think it would improve performance?

Comment: Can you post some code, please? How many particles are we talking about here? Have you done some benchmarks already?

Comment: So I was thinking the module pattern as described in https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#modules was something that could definitely apply to my own use case, I would create as many Particle instances as needed.

Comment: Quoting from you don't know js:
Warning: We are not calling new User() here, on purpose, despite the fact that probably seems more common to most readers. User() is just a function, not a class to be instantiated, so it's just called normally. Using new would be inappropriate and actually waste resources.

Comment: @MathieuJouhet theres no performance improvement because of the closures. One main Object, many Objects referring to it vie prototype vs. multiple Functions, many Objects referring to it via Closure functions

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonasw so you confirm that I should keep my particles as abjects and not as module instances right?

Comment: Oh, that should be called "factory (function)" not "module". And no, using `new` is only inappropriate with factory functions, it is appropriate for constructor functions (classes). And there, [using the prototype does the opposite of wasting resources](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572).

Comment: @MathieuJouhet its up to you. Inheritance is much easier with prototypes, the factory pattern is good for private propertys...

Comment: @bergi error:infinite link following loop ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, @Bergi are you saying that the module pattern as described in "you don't know js" should be called a factory instead?
Or is the factory pattern a particular subset of the module pattern?

Comment: @MathieuJouhet [Yes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/issues/956) :-)

Comment: Well thanks a lot for opening the issue on their repo! That's what I was about to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bergi and @jonasw I was able to get good answers:

The module pattern I was referring to was the one described in the first book in the "You don't know js" series. As pointed out by @bergi, it should be named factory instead (see bergi's [issue on github](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/issues/956))

**Conclusion:** I was definitely right using a class with prototype methods and creating my particles using `new`.