# Is it acceptable to define a property with a custom getter on an object's prototype?

Tags: javascript

I have an object defined that will instantiated 1000s of time when the code runs.  One of the properties of the object is a calculated value.  I'm using a custom getter with Object.defineProperty.  All examples that I've seen define the property on the object itself.

However, if the property is derived with a function, wouldn't it conserve more memory to define the property on the object's prototype?  I've been unable to find an example like that.

The code example below seems to work, but is doing it this way acceptable?  Is it more memory conservative than defining the property on the object?

```
var Person=function(first,last)
{
    this.firstName=first
    this.lastName=last
}
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "fullName", { get: function() { return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`} })

var a =new Person("Jane","Doe")
console.log(a.fullName)  //"Jane Doe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is doing it this way acceptable?

Yes, totally. Using ES6 `class` syntax made defining accessor properties on prototype objects even easier, it's quite common.

```
class Person {
  constructor(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
  }
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}    
var a = new Person("Jane", "Doe");
console.log(a.fullName)  //"Jane Doe"
```

> Is it more memory conservative than defining the property on the object?

[Yes, definitely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572).