# Is this a way to implement ES6 private class members?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

Stepping outside of the box in terms of how member functions are normally declared in ES6 classes, is this not an effective way to implement a distinction between private and public members?

```
class IncrementedNumber {
    constructor(x) {
        const xPlus1 = x + 1;
        this.getDouble = () => 2 * xPlus1;
        this.getQuadruple = () => 2 * this.getDouble();
    }
}
const x = new IncrementedNumber(6);
console.log(x.getDouble());    // 2 * 7 -> 14
console.log(x.getQuadruple()); // 2 * (2 * 7) -> 28
```

The class has a private member that is 1 greater than the number supplied as an argument to its constructor. The class then offers public operations for doubling and quadrupling the number.

The private member xPlus1 is *superprivate* insofar as even class members can't access it—*if they lie outside of the constructor*. But class methods can be defined *inside* the constructor, so what difference does it make?

The one loose end I see is that private members, in contrast to public members, are accessed without being prefixed by "this". But that seems negligible; one might even see it as a benefit, as it forces the developer to be aware of the respective visibilities of the class's members.

Are there downsides to this that I'm not seeing? We *can* define public methods outside of the constructor, but are we married to doing so? Given that public fields must be defined inside the constructor, is there some reason public methods must be defined outside of it?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there downsides to this that I'm not seeing?

- [It is less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572)
- [It does not work properly with inheritance](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)

Other than that, yes it properly achieves privacy through closure scope, and is sometimes used for this.