# Javascript class method redefine with extend original content

Tags: javascript, class, redefine

I have a class like:

```
var TTable = function(name){  
  this.props= function(){
    this.properties=new TProperty();
    this.properties.Add("wfstart","Workflow start","L",false);
    this.properties.Add("wfend","Workflow end","L",false);
  }
  this.props(); 
}
```

I'd like to extend the TTable later with a new row of code in the props function like:

```
function addfeat(){
    //Add features
    var origprop = TTable.props;
    Reflect.defineProperty(TTable.prototype, 'props', { value: function() {
        origprop();
        this.properties.Add("ttype","Tipus","N",false);
    }});
}
```

So in my mind when I instantiate the TTable will be like this:

```
var TTable = function(name){  
  this.props= function(){
    this.properties=new TProperty();
    this.properties.Add("wfstart","Workflow start","L",false);
    this.properties.Add("wfend","Workflow end","L",false);
    this.properties.Add("ttype","Tipus","N",false);
  }
  this.props(); 
}
```

But the first code not working.
Please help me.

Comment: What the OP actually might looking for is [JavaScript "method modification"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20%22method%20modification%22)

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying `TTable.prototype.props`, but your class isn't actually using that prototype when it creates a `props` function for every instance. [It shouldn't be doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572):

```
var TTable = function(name) { 
  this.props(); 
};
TTable.prototype.props = function() {
  this.properties = new TProperty();
  this.properties.Add("wfstart","Workflow start","L",false);
  this.properties.Add("wfend","Workflow end","L",false);
};
```

With this, your approach would actually work, given a few other fixes:

```
function addfeat(){
  // Add features
  var origprop = TTable.prototype.props;
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^
  TTable.prototype.props = function() {
//                       ^ assignment is sufficient, no need to `defineProperty`
    origprop.call(this);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^ call as method on correct instance
    this.properties.Add("ttype","Tipus","N",false);
  };
}
```