# Arrow functions, methods and bind. Memory usage and performance

Tags: javascript, bind, arrow-functions

Please check the code below, I'm not sure if my JS is correct, I usually use TS.
My question is: What is the difference in memory usage and performance in these two usages?

Memory: As I understand `sum2` will occupy memory with every instance of Test which I create, while `sum1` will do it once.

Performance: If I use `bind` with any of these methods, it will create a wrapper function which will cause performance degradation.

Please recommend resources, where I can study this deeply: methods vs arrow function + bind usage of them, memory consumption and performance - their cons and pros

```
class Test {

  a = 100;
  
  constructor() {
    this.sum2 = (b) => this.a+b;
  }

  sum1(b) {
    return this.a+b;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you determined that either performance or memory consumption is actually an issue in your application or is this more theoretical?

Comment: "what is the difference in memory usage and performance in this two usages" — Step 1: Pick a JS engine to performance test.

Comment: The difference between arrow functions and bound methods will be negligible. Measure it yourself if you really care. Use the one you like better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

They are the same in terms of performance.

```
` Chrome/123
-------------------------------------------------------
arrow           1.00x | x1000000000 325 329 333 334 337
bound function  1.01x | x1000000000 328 330 331 332 334
bound method    1.02x | x1000000000 330 334 334 337 340
method          1.02x | x1000000000 331 331 334 336 343
function        1.02x | x1000000000 332 333 336 342 346
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/124
-------------------------------------------------------
arrow           1.00x | x1000000000 250 257 259 261 291
method          1.00x | x1000000000 251 254 254 256 272
function        1.00x | x1000000000 251 252 256 279 299
bound function  7.48x |  x100000000 187 187 189 192 193
bound method    7.60x |  x100000000 190 192 197 198 199
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000000">

class Test {

  a = 100;
  
  constructor() {
    this.sum2 = (b) => this.a+b;
  }

  sum1(b) {
    return this.a+b;
  }
  
  sum3 = function(b){
    return this.a+b;
  }

}


const test = new Test;
const method = test.sum1.bind(test);
const func = test.sum3.bind(test);


// @benchmark arrow
test.sum2(100);

// @benchmark method
test.sum1(100);

// @benchmark bound method
method(100);

// @benchmark function
test.sum3(100);

// @benchmark bound function
func(100);


</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Regarding instance creation performance: no difference either:

```
` Chrome/123
-------------------------------------------------
function  1.00x | x1000000000 330 337 338 340 343
method    1.00x | x1000000000 330 334 334 335 342
arrow     1.00x | x1000000000 331 333 334 336 337
-------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/124
--------------------------------------------------
method     1.00x | x1000000000 248 251 262 283 293
arrow     52.82x |   x10000000 131 144 205 217 220
function  57.66x |   x10000000 143 149 174 176 179
--------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000000">

class TestArrow {
  sum = (a, b) => a + b;
}
class TestMethod {
  sum(a, b){ return a + b; }
}
class TestFunction {
  sum = function (a, b){ return a + b; }
}


// @benchmark arrow
new TestArrow;

// @benchmark method
new TestMethod;

// @benchmark function
new TestFunction;

</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```