# What advantages are gained by using constructors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working to refactor a large and undocumented JavaScript Library.  One of the proposed refactorings is to implement constructors in the code as opposed to dynamically constructing an object.  Example Below:

Instead of:

```
var myLibObj = new Object();
myLibObj.SomeProperty =
{
   FooFunction: function(){/*Do Something Cool*/}
}
```

The proposed change:

```
function myLibObjConstructor(){
  this.SomeProperty = {FooFunction: function(){/*Do Something Cool*/}}
  return this;
}

var myLibObj = new myLibObjConstructor();
```

Is there any advantage to changing the code?

Comment: good question! but possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage would be that myLibObjConstructor can be reused somewhere else

Comment: That's also a pretty huge advantage, and one of the most basic principles of good programming.

Answer (score 1):

If it's existing code that already works without the need for constructors, the benefits of moving toward constructors could be marginal or non-existent.

However, the general advantages of using constructors would be:

- Object instances have a "type" i.e. you can check `instanceof` or `constructor` to make decisions given just an object instance.
- The most important of all, you get encapsulation. You can encapsulate "private" properties, inheritance etc., leading to cleaner and more portable code.
- Using a constructor is more concise and more conventional than instantiating a generic object first and tacking on properties.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, your question boils down to prototype vs constructors. 
which is a great question and a lot has been written about it. Including here.

[How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

[Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)

also good reading here:
http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm