# How to use prototype method in class constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, methods, prototype-programming

I habe read here about defining method for a Javascript class [Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor) and I choose prototype way. But I get an issue, for example:

```
function MyClass() {};
MyClass.prototype.Hide = function() {};

function MyClass() {
  this.layout = $("<div>", {id: "layout1"}).text("My content");
  this.button = $("<input />", {id: "button1"});
  this.layout.append(this.button);
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    //How can I call hide
    this.Hide()//Error
  });
}
MyClass.prototype.Hide = function() {
  this.layout.hide("slow");
}
```

How can I call the prototype function in the contructor? I have try the forward declaration for the prototype method, but I think the issue is the way I call it, *this.Hide()* is no help!
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong `this`. The `this` you're using to call `Hide()` is actually the `#button` element. Assign the `this` that is the `MyClass` object to a local variable, and then use that in the click delegate:

```
...
this.layout.append(this.button);
var $this = this;
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $this.Hide();
});
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
  //How can I call hide
  this.Hide()//Error
});
```

In this line of code, `this` refers to the button (it's inside a function).
Before ths binding, you can define `var that = this;` and use `that`in the callback:

```
function MyClass() {};
MyClass.prototype.Hide = function() {};

function MyClass() {
  var that = this;
  this.layout = $("<div>", {id: "layout1"}).text("My content");
  this.button = $("<input />", {id: "button1"});
  this.layout.append(this.button);
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    //How can I call hide
    that.Hide();
  });
}
MyClass.prototype.Hide = function() {
  this.layout.hide("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `Hide` in the constructor. You're calling it in the `click` callback, which has a different context (`this` is different).

Use a temp variable to store a reference to the current object:

```
var t;
t = this;

...click(function () {
  t.hide();
});
```

Also, JavaScript convention is that `PascalCase` is used for constructors, and `camelCase` is used for functions/methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can call prototype methods from constructor. You problem is that you are loosing context inside anonymous click function. So you have two options:

```
// 1. link to original object
var self = this;
$("#button1").click(function() {
    self.Hide();
});

// 2. use proxy (bind) to invoke method in correct context
// there is built in function available in jQuery
$("#button1").click($.proxy(function() {
    this.Hide();
}, this));
```

Comment: The second solution you have is fancy, but I think we can both agree that the first one is easier to read.

Comment: It depends. Very often using binding to correct object context is the only way to do things.