# whey append methods to the Object prototype instead of put them on constructor function ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Here is my problem, i have one object Car & theirs properties, i defined a method inside the object. but i think it is recommended to append this method to the object protytype, but why? what are the advantages and disadvantages? Thank you :)

What i did..

```
function Car (desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = function getInfo() {
        return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
    };
}
```

Recommended :

```
Car.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
};
```

Comment: @bfavaretto No, I think this is more of what he's looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772307/declaring-javascript-object-method-in-constructor-function-vs-in-prototype

Comment: very related, but different. @SethenMaleno has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you did results in every instance of `Car` having it's own copy of the `getInfo` method. Putting it on the prototype gives a that one function definition to every instance automatically.