# Why we use "prototype" property to add methods to constructor instances?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I am creating a JavaScript constructor. Consider this example:

```
function Student(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

Student.prototype.printName = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
}

var s = new Student("Eden");
s.printName();
```

This above code works all well. But I can write the same this way also:

```
function Student(name)
{
    this.name = name;

    this.printName = function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var s = new Student("Eden");
s.printName();
```

I feel the second method is correct way because `printName` should be own property of new object not an inherited property. Adding to `prototype` makes it an inherited property.

Why do developer prefer the first method?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9772307/218196

Comment: Why do you feel that `printName` should be an own property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By attaching functions directly to `this` in a constructor, that means *every* instance of `Student` has it's own copy of `printName`. That isn't very efficient. By attaching it to the `prototype` chain of `Student`, there is only one copy of the `printName` function and any instance of `Student` has it in it's prototype chain.

While there are other differences in those two approaches for attaching function to objects, that is the simplest and easiest to remember.

If you want the full dictionary of reasons how the two differ, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310914/1011616) to an extremely similar question.

Comment: This is true. Try to think of properties add to the prototype as static. They are the same for all instances. If you add them to 'this' you are creating multiple functions that all do the exact same thing.