# How do I represent a return type in a Typescript interface file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the difference between the following code:

```
changeName(): ng.IPromise<any>;
```

and

```
changeName: () => ng.IPromise<any>;
```

I understand one is a return type but I am confused about the first one.

Here's the function body:

```
changeName = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
        var self = this;
        self.chnAction = "PREFERENCES.CHANGE_NAME.SUBMITTING_BUTTON_TEXT";
        self.chnErrorMessage = null;
        return self.uss.changeName(
            self.chnNewFirstName,
            self.chnNewLastName)
            .then(
            (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
                self.chnAction = "PREFERENCES.CHANGE_NAME.SUBMITTED_BUTTON_TEXT";
                self.chnNewFirstName = '';
                self.chnNewLastName = '';
                self.chnErrorMessage = null;
                self.logout();
                return this.$state.go('home.auth', { content: 'change_name_success' });
            },
            (error: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): ng.IPromise<any> => {
                if (error.status === 500) {
                    self.chnErrorMessage = 'AUTH_SERVICE.UNABLE_TO_CONTACT_SERVER';
                } else {
                    var errors: string[] = [];
                    Object.keys(error.data.modelState).forEach((key) => {
                        errors.push.apply(errors, error.data.modelState[key]);
                    });
                    self.chnErrorMessage = errors[0];
                    self.chnErrorMessages = errors;
                    self.chnAction = "PREFERENCES.CHANGE_NAME.SUBMIT_BUTTON_TEXT";
                }
                return this.$q.reject(error);
            });
    };
```

Comment: The first one is a method of the interface, the second on is a property (of type Function) of the interface

Comment: You can now use `this` instead of `self` throughout, since `this` will carry across any `=>` arrow functions. Also, there is no difference between methods and function properties on an interface (see my answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental difference is this:

- `changeName(): ng.IPromise<any>;` represents a **method**.
- `changeName: () => ng.IPromise<any>;` represents a **property** that can hold a function (this matches `changeName = (): ng.IPromise<any> => { ... };` since that is assigning a function to a property).

Because of that the differences between properties and methods apply. Here's one example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    myMethod(): string;
    myProperty: () => string;
}

class MyBaseClass implements MyInterface {
    myMethod() {
        return "string";
    }

    myProperty = () => "string";
}

class MyChildClass extends MyBaseClass {
    myMethod() {
        return super.myMethod();
    }

    myProperty = () => super.myProperty(); // error
}
```

The reason why using an arrow function property instead of a method is sometimes done is because arrow functions assigned to properties preserve the value of `this` no matter what is bound to it...

```
class MyClass {
    myMethod() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    myProperty = () => console.log(this);
}

new MyClass().myMethod.call({});   // outputs {}
new MyClass().myProperty.call({}); // outputs the instance of MyClass
```

...since the value of `this` is preserved in the constructor...

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        // captures this here
        var _this = this;
        // guaranteed to always use instance of class for `this`
        this.myProperty = function () { return console.log(_this); };
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        // not guarnateed to always use instance of class
        console.log(this);
    };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

*Sidenote*: You can read about `.call` in JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 3):

On an **interface** there's no difference. Here's an interface that uses both notations (let's use `string` as the return type for clarity):

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo(): string; // preferred
    bar: () => string;
}
```

Here, `foo` is a function with return type `string`. And the type of `bar` is also a function with the return type `string`. The first notation is usually cleaner. The following object matches the interface:

```
let x: MyInterface = {
    foo: () => "",
    bar: () => ""
}
```

On a **class**, one notation is adds the function to the prototype, while the other adds it as a property of the new instance (`this.myFunc = ...`). This has exactly the same effect that it has in JavaScript (and you almost never need to add a function/method as an instance property).

```
class MyClass {
    bar(): string { return ""; } // prototype, preferred
    foo = () => ""; // instance property
}
```

As we can see below, the class fits our original interface, even though I've reversed `foo` and `bar`. Therefore the interface does not impose the implementation detail of how the method will be set.

```
let y: MyInterface = new MyClass();
```

Note that a class is not a special type - it's effectively an interface plus an implementation. So you can use `MyClass` as you would any other type (whether defined as an interface or class):

```
let z: MyClass = {
    foo: () => "",
    bar: () => ""
}
```

With respect to types (which is what an interface defines), there is no difference, though when used in a class the notations produce different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to show whole code sample. Hopefully the following example will explain your question:

```
class MyClass {

    changeName(): number {
        return 5;
    }

    changeName2 = ():number => {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

transpiles to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.changeName2 = function () {
            return 5;
        };
    }
    MyClass.prototype.changeName = function () {
        return 5;
    };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%09%0A%09changeName()%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%09%09return%205%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09changeName2%20%3D%20()%3Anumber%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09return%205%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)]

There is an in-depth explanation of the differences between these two definitions in: [Declaring javascript object method in constructor function vs. in prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772307/declaring-javascript-object-method-in-constructor-function-vs-in-prototype)

Comment: I added the function body so you can see how it looks. Sorry but I'm not very clear about what you mean. Can you have a look and let me know based on the function itself? Thanks

Comment: @Sophia: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I tried to show you what happens when you use the former and the later definitions in the playground. The difference is that the transpilation result is different. For your purposes, I guess you can think about them as if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

*What is the difference between the following code*

As you don't have added more code to see what actually is been configured. As i can see you have two lines of code:

```
changeName(): ng.IPromise<any>;
```

As per this code one can understand that it is returning a promise of type any, which could be anything, an `object, string, array, number` etc.

So one can say that the `changeName()` will return a `ng.IPromise` value of type of `<any>`thing.

---

While the other line of code:

```
changeName: () => ng.IPromise<any>;
```

Says that this function will return a value `ng.IPromise` of `<any>`thing.

Comment: I updated my question to show the function. I hope it makes it more clear.  Based on this can you tell me how you think I should be setting up the interface.