# How can I recreate array methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm trying to backwards engineer the array methods push, pull, shift, unshift, but I can't seem to figure out how to a) construct it b) call it.  How could I do this?  Here are the conditions:

> returns an empty array object. this object should have the
>   following methods: push(val) adds val to the end of the array
>   pop() removes a value from the end and returns it unshift(val) adds
>   val to the beginning of the array shift() removes a value from the
>   beginning and returns it the goal of this problem is to reverse
>   engineer what array methods are actually doing and return an object
>   that has those methods

Here is what I initially thought it should look like.

```
function createArray() {
    //CODE HERE

  this.push = function Push(value){
                if(index >= 0){
                 Mainarray[index++]=value;}
               };

   this.pop = function (){
                if(index >= 0){
                  index--;
                 return Mainarray[index];
                }
                else{
                  // display message of Empty Array
                  console.log('Error: Item is not array');
                }
              };

   this.unshift = function(){return ;};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use prototypes — like this:

```
function YourArray() {
  this.arr = [];
  this.index = 0;
}

YourArray.prototype.push = function( value ) {
  this.arr[ this.index++ ] = value;
  return this;
}

var arr = new YourArray();

arr.push('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function NewArray() {
    this.array = [];
}; /* Class */

NewArray.prototype.push = function(data) {
    this.array.push(data);
} /* Method */
/* You should use prototypes, because all methods will became common, and if you are created methods like this.pop = function (){} then any instance will copy this functions */


var n = new NewArray();
n.push(2);
console.log(n);
```

[Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the push method by assigning you array at position the length of the same array a value.

This is the prototype for the push:

```
Array.prototype.push = function(element) {
    this[this.length] = element;
};
```

and this is for the pop method:

```
Array.prototype.pop = function() {
    var key = this.stack.pop();
    var prop = this.object[key];
    delete this.object[key];
    return prop;
};
```

You can make your own methods by changing the prototype names.
*push to mypush or sthing*

Example for your push function createArray:

```
this.push = function pushValue(value) {
    this.arr[this.arr.length] = value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I used native arrays methods as values assigned to keys in the returned object. The trick is to declare an array inside the object and use it as a reference. It should pass the checks you`re looking for.

```
function createArray() {
    //CODE HERE
    return {
       arr: [],
       push: function (val) {this.arr.push(val)},
       pop: function() {return this.arr.pop()},
       unshift: function (val) {return this.arr.unshift(val)},
       shift: function() {return this.arr.shift()}
    }
}
```