# Nicer JavaScript object initialization

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a type of object which I've declared like this:

```
function Stream(id, info, container){
    var self = this;

    this.id = id;
    this.paddedId = ("00000" + this.id).substr(-5,5);
    this.live = info['live'];
    this.autoplay = info['autoplay'];
...
```

I instantiate that with:

```
var stream = new Stream(1, streamInfo, "stream");
```

On some occasions I instantiate several objects of that type at once. The object also has functions, I want to initiate it a bit cleaner, how can I do it like this, but keep my functions? See here:

```
var stream = new Stream({
        'id': 1
        'live': true
        'autoplay': false
     });
```

Or at least something similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the parameters you want to pass to the constructor into a 'options' parameter.

If you want to keep function on 'Stream', use its prototype to define functions on it which will make them available on all Stream's instances.

```
function Stream(options){
   this.id = options.id;
   this.autoplay = options.autoplay;
   // ... rest of variable initialization
}

Stream.prototype.foo = function() {
  // ...
}
 
Stream.prototype.bar = function() {
 // ...
}
```

Usage :

```
var stream = new Stream({ id : 'myId', autoplay : true });
stream.foo();
stream.bar();
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way to do this, can you explain the difference of using prototype functions vs. just declaring them 'normally'?

Comment: Basically, each object's instance in javascript has it's prototype, which is the equivalent to class definition we all are used to in oop languages. If you would define a function in the constructor of `Stream`, it would be created each time the constructor is invoked, leading to poorer performance. [Here's a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4508498/4716922) to a similar question

Comment: Thanks! Very clear now. Another question I have: I had issues with invoking functions within the constructor, but they weren't initialized yet. Wouldn't I have problems with this when invoking prototype functions?

Comment: Well, I've tried fiddling with prototype function invocation inside the constructor and had no issues
`function Test(){
 this.myVariable = 'some value';
  this.do();
  
  console.log(this.myVariable);
};


Test.prototype.do= function(){
 this.myVariable = 'other value';
};

new Test();`

[here's that fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbzyxj3h/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use anonymous functions like this

```js
var MyClass = (function () {

    var self = function (options) {

        // these will be our default options
        this.options = {
            name: 'John',
            lastName: 'doe'
        }

        // here we just extend the object
        $.extend(this.options, options);
    };

    self.prototype.get = function (attr) {
        return this.options[attr];
    };

    self.prototype.set = function (attrName, attrValue) {
        this.options[attrName] = attrValue;
    };

    self.prototype.whatsMyName = function () {
        $('.' + this.get('name')).html(this.get('name') + ' ' + this.get('lastName'));
    };

    return self;
})();

var Tom = new MyClass({
    name: 'Tom',
    lastName: 'Mathew'
});

var Allen = new MyClass({
    name: 'Allen',
    lastName: 'C'
});

Tom.whatsMyName();
Allen.whatsMyName();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="Tom"></div>
<div class="Allen"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a config object in Stream Constructor and then get values from that

```
function Stream(fonfig){
   var self = this;
   var info = config.info || {};
   this.id = config.id;

   this.paddedId = ("00000" + this.id).substr(-5,5);
   this.live = info['live'];
   this.autoplay = info['autoplay'];
}
```

and you can call as you mentioned

```
var stream = new Stream({
    'id': 1
    'live': true
    'autoplay': false
 });
```