# How can i bind control events to a function declared using javascripts prototyping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototype

I'm trying to create a html page and add some javascript event handling via a prototype object, so in theory we would have:

1: A standard html page which would create a prototyped object and call a prototype function during the bodys "onLoad" event.

2. This function would in turn associate a controls event with a second prototype function in the class.

In this example i'd like to capture the textboxes change event, but the actual pages will have a fair number of controls.

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>  <head>
>     <title></title>
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
>     <script src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
>     <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
>     <script src="searchAddress.js"></script>
>     <script>
>         function loadIt() {
>             SearchAddressController = new SearchAddressControllerBase;
>             SearchAddressController.BindTheCotrols();
>         }
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body onload="loadIt()">
>
>     <input name="textHouseNo" type="text" id="textHouseNo" value="" placeholder="House No" data-clear-btn="true" maxlength="20" />
>     <input name="texPostcode" type="text" id="texPostcode" value="" placeholder="Post Code" data-clear-btn="true" maxlength="20" />
>     <button></button>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The code that is in searchAddress.js is

```
var SearchAddressControllerBase = function () {
    this.houseNumber = null;
    this.postCode = null;
};

SearchAddressControllerBase.prototype.GeneralEventHandler = function (c, e) {
    // would like the text boxes change event to land here...

}

SearchAddressControllerBase.prototype.BindTheCotrols = function () {

    // bind the controls here
    $("#textHouseNo").change(this.GeneralEventHandler('textHouseNo', 'change'));
};
```

I need to create this separation between the html and js as it will ultimately be generated rather than hand-cranked.

Any help explaining how i can get the BindTheControls function to make the change event for textHouseNo route to GeneralEventHandler would be appreciated.

A couple of the the links i've been looking at are:
[Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)
and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: What is the problem? I'm confused what you are trying to ask...

Comment: The BindTheCotrols function gets called but i'm unsure how to get it to usethe GeneralEventHandler to handle events from the html controls. Have updated my question so hopefully its a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close; when you do this:

`$("#textHouseNo").change(this.GeneralEventHandler('textHouseNo', 'change'));`

You are actually invoking `GeneralEventHandler` immediately instead of assigning it to the change event. **You need to change it to:**

`$("#textHouseNo").change(this.GeneralEventHandler);`

Then in the handler method, you can get info about the event like this:

```
function (evt) {
  var el = evt.currentTarget
  var type = evt.type;
  var id = el.id
  var val = el.value

  console.log(id, type, val)
}
```

## Check out the working demo

```js
var SearchAddressControllerBase = function () {
    this.houseNumber = null;
    this.postCode = null;
};

SearchAddressControllerBase.prototype.GeneralEventHandler = function (evt) {
    // would like the text boxes change event to land here...
  
  var el = evt.currentTarget
  var type = evt.type;
  var id = el.id
  var val = el.value
  
  console.log(id, type, val)
}

SearchAddressControllerBase.prototype.BindTheCotrols = function () {

    // bind the controls here
    $("#textHouseNo").change(this.GeneralEventHandler);
};

 function loadIt() {
    SearchAddressController = new SearchAddressControllerBase;
    SearchAddressController.BindTheCotrols();
}


// would be called from "onload"
loadIt()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="textHouseNo" type="text" id="textHouseNo" value="" placeholder="House No" data-clear-btn="true" maxlength="20" />
    <input name="texPostcode" type="text" id="texPostcode" value="" placeholder="Post Code" data-clear-btn="true" maxlength="20" />
    <button></button>
```