# Why do we add methods using the prototype property of the constructor function?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

One thing I don't understand with prototypes and constructor functions..

Say I have this constructor function that will create an object with a 'name' property and a 'logName' method

```
function MyExample(param1){
  this.name = param1;
};

MyExample.prototype.logName = function(){
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

I understand I just added a method (logName) to the constructor function's (myExample) prototype..so that when I create a new object (me) using this constructor function that object will inherit the 'name' property and the 'logName' method. The logName method will be part of new object's (me) **proto** property

```
var me = new MyExample('bob');
me.logName(); //bob
```

..But why not just add the logName method to the object the constructor function is creating? (not the prototype of the constructor function) Wouldn't that provide the same result? Even though 'logName' will not be part of the new object's **proto** property.

```
function MyExample(param1){
   this.name = param1;
   this.logName = function(){
      console.log(this.name)
   };
};

var me = new MyExample('bob');
me.logName(); //bob
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your second example you recreate the `logName` function every time you create a new instance of `MyExample`. If you use the `MyExample`'s prototype then one `logName` method is shared across all instances of the `MyExample` object and context is passed around automatically.

The prototype also allows you to add a new method at a later point that can be accessed by already-existing objects of that type or globally modify a method for all objects of a type.

This question touches on the same topic if you would like more information, [Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with creating the method in the constructor is that it isn't being shared among all instances of `MyExample`.

Instead, each `MyExample` has it's own copy of the function. It ends up taking up more memory as the number of instances goes up and if for some reason you want to modify *all* `MyExample`s at run time, you have to change every single instances function instead of modifying the prototype.

It's the difference between everyone looking at the same "copy" of Wikipedia versus everyone saving all of Wikipedia to their hard drive and reading that. It pointlessly uses up extra hard drive space and if Wikipedia is updated, everyone is wrong until they download the new version.

If for some reason you need a function which is very similar across instances but will be slightly different for each instance (for example, using closure variables) then creating methods in the constructor may be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Adding methods in the prototype gives your code better abstraction.

For example, since the methods are not tied to the instances, you are able to call them on non-instances which are compatible enough. Like this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call({0:'a', 1:'b', length:2}); // ["a", "b"]
```

If you only defined your methods on the instances, it would be necessary to create an useless instance in order to borrow the method:

```
[].slice.call({0:'a', 1:'b', length:2}); // ["a", "b"]
```

Additionally, defining a method inside th constructor means that each instance will receive a different copy.

```
new MyExample('bob').logName === new MyExample('bob').logName // false
```

This means you will waste more memory.