# Pass function to javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my index.html, I have this code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var self = this;
    var submit = function() {
        alert("Test");
    }
    const form = new Form(self.submit);
})
```

In my Form.js, I have this code,

```
class Form() {
    constructor(func) {
        var self = this;
        // ...
        $("submitBtn").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           self.func();
        });
        // ...
    }
}
```

Why my function is not executing after the submitBtn is clicked?
I used self to get the "this" value. I cant use "new Form(self.submit())" because It will execute the function once the line is read.

Comment: Well, you do pass "func" to your constructor, but then you do nothing with it... Is this your whole code, or did you remove parts of it?

Comment: you haven't bound `submit` to anything, just pass an anonymous function to the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `submit` function is a **local variable**, not a property of `this`. Thus you need:

```
const form = new Form(submit);
```

Similarly, in your constructor, `func` doesn't have anything to do with `self`; it should just be

```
  func();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointy answers the question. I just want to add that constructor is a place where you usually declare and initialize instance properties, and it's better to register click event in a class method, something like:

```
class Form{
  constructor(){}
  click(func){
     $("submitBtn").click((e)=>{
           e.preventDefault();
           func();
        });
  }

}
```

Also you dont need to cache the scope `var self = this` as long as you use arrow function. This answer could be useful [Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)