# defineProperty descriptor Parameter and Object.prototype dilemma

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype, ecmascript-5, defineproperty

I am using `defineProperty` to create an object properties,.Does the `descriptor` parameter in the function necessarily need to be an `object`. Here is the code:

```
var config=new Object();
var defineProp = function ( obj, key, value ){
config.value = value; // why should this parameter be an object?
Object.defineProperty( obj, key, config );
};
```

Why do we have to pass an Object to the `Descriptor` parameter

I have below two code pieces, where I am making a constructor and then creating objects using it.Both the codes return the same output in console. Does using `.prototype.Methodname` change anything?

### 1

```
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
this.model = model;
this.year = year;
this.miles = miles;
}

Car.prototype.toString = function () {
return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
};
// Usage:
var civic = new Car( "Honda Civic", 2017, 30000 );

console.log( civic.toString() );
```

### 2

```
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
this.model = model;
this.year = year;
this.miles = miles;
this.toString = function () {
return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
};
}

var civic = new Car( "Honda Civic", 2017, 30000 );
console.log( civic.toString() );
```

The code usage is as follows:

```
var civicSport= Object.create( person );

defineProp(civicSport, "topSpeed", "120mph");//function created above
console.log(civicSport);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of using prototype, vs defining methods straight in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)

Comment: But these answers don't suffice the first part of this question :`Does the descriptor parameter in the function necessarily need to be an object?` ,i.e, defineProperty parameters

Answer (score 0):

The `descriptor` parameter refers to the property being defined or modified, so we need to refer it as a key value pair( **key**= property being defined/modified, **value**= modified or assigned value to property). Thus `descriptor` must be an `Object`

For more details, please see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: thanks for your feedback. But lets see this `var driver=new Object; defineProp(driver, "topSpeed", "100mph");` Here the key(`topSpeed`) and value(`100mph`) are being passed separately, so why pass an object for the 'Value' part.

Comment: No, i guess you are not understanding it correctly. We can't directly change value of 'topSpeed'. Using Object.defineProperty we do not assign/modify value of the property but add/modify descriptor of property 'topSpeed'. And property descriptor keys(like 'value', 'set', 'get', 'writable') are the ones which are used to define property values, thus descriptor is an object.