# Why must set prototype instead of invoking methods directly in function constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm diving into ExpressJS lib at `/lib/router/index.js`, it declares as below:

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
  var opts = options || {};

  function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  }

  // mixin Router class functions
  setPrototypeOf(router, proto)

  router.params = {};
  router._params = [];
  router.caseSensitive = opts.caseSensitive;
  router.mergeParams = opts.mergeParams;
  router.strict = opts.strict;
  router.stack = [];

  return router;
};

proto.handle = function handle(req, res, out) {
  var self = this;

  debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);

  var idx = 0;
  var protohost = getProtohost(req.url) || ''
  .........
}
```

I confused why they can not invoke directly, by a given way like that

```
return function(req, res, next) {
    handle(req, res, next);
}
```

it seems it is clearer and simpler.

Comment: Is this information you are looking for? [https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/](https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/) or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508313/advantages-of-using-prototype-vs-defining-methods-straight-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Because they want to invoke it as a method, with access to all the properties of the `router` instance. Admittedly, they could have used

```
handle.call(router, req, res, next)
```

but if you already inherit it from your prototype then why not just call it as a method directly.

Comment: yes, instead of invoking .call() for each of methods, inheriting prototype support to call all of those directly. The reason maybe just for convenient in coding style

Comment: What type of `proto` in this case `var proto = module.exports = function(options) `.  As my understand, the `proto` is type of function, so I confused why they're able to declare ```proto.handle = function handle(req, res, out) {...}```

Comment: @BinhLe `proto` is a (function) object, that's all what matters - any object can have properties and be inherited from. Admittedly, this is confusing, they could (should) have separated it between constructor function and normal prototype object.. However, the instance (`router`) is a function as well, so why not - they needed to inherit from `Function.prototype` anyway.

Comment: all elements in JS are objects. I understand well. Thanks @Bergi