# What are the benefits of adding new methods on a derived class rather than the class itself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

for personal learning purposes, I'm trying to understand Winston's package design structure and the purpose behind each of its modules but I can't figure this one out.

In Winstons package, there is the core `Logger` class in the [logger.js](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/3.1.0/lib/winston/logger.js) module which implements the main functionality of the logger and provides some public methods such as the `logger.log` method. It also implements the transform stream methods for internal use.

Then there is a derived class in [create-logger.js](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/3.1.0/lib/winston/create-logger.js) module called `DerivedLogger` that extends the Logger class and it seems that its sole purpose is to add optimized level methods to the loggers prototype. This `DerivedLogger` class is then instantiated and exported in a factory function at the bottom of the module.

My question is, Why was the `DerivedLogger` class needed? would there be any difference in performance if those level methods were instead added on the `Logger` class prototype itself and then have the factory function instantiate the `Logger` class directly? the only reason I could think of is that perhaps the `DerivedLogger` class is added for modularity purposes only? can someone help me understand the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one was very interesting, thanks for pointing it out!

---

**In short**: It has nothing to do with code-structure, it's a performance optimization. The comment states as much:

> Create a new class derived logger for which the levels can be attached to the prototype of. This is a V8 optimization that is well know to increase performance of prototype functions.

Personally, I think this needs citation (and I wouldn't accept it in a code-review). Luckily, I *think* I found the "optimization" that the author was talking about:

[This article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes) by Mathias (a Google engineer that works on V8) talks about speeding up JavaScript execution with correct usage of `prototype`. The article has a **lot** of details and is really worth the read if you're learning.

The optimization found in Winston boils down to this:

> The `getAttribute()` method is found on the `Element.prototype`. That means each time we call `anchor.getAttribute()`, the JavaScript engine needs to…
>
> - check that `getAttribute` is not on the anchor object itself,
> - check that the direct prototype is `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype`,
> - assert absence of `getAttribute` there,
> - check that the next prototype is `HTMLElement.prototype`,
> - assert absence of `getAttribute` there as well,
> - eventually check that the next prototype is `Element.prototype`,
> - and that `getAttribute` is present there.
>
> That’s a total of 7 checks! Since this kind of code is pretty common on the web, engines apply tricks to reduce the number of checks necessary for property loads on prototypes.

This is **roughly** applicable to Winston as follows:

- *Methods* on *Classes* are defined on the `prototype`-object of said class
- Every time a *method* is called on an *instance*, the engine needs to find the `prototype` that the called *method* is attached to.
- In doing so, it takes the prototype for the *instance*-class that you're calling the method on and checks to find the called *method* on it's `prototype`
- If it can't find it (e.g. because the *method* is *inherited*), it walks up the `prototype`-chain to the next *class* and looks there
- This continues until either the method is found (and executed sub-sequentially) or the end of the `prototype`-chain is reached (and an error is thrown).

By running `_setupLevels()` in the constructor, the level-methods are directly attached to the prototype of the specific logger-implementations *instance*. This means that the class-hierarchy can grow arbitrarily large: **The `prototype`-chain lookup only takes 1 step to find the method**

Here is another (simplified) example:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.setup();
    }
    testInherit() {
        console.log("Inherited method called");
    }
    setup() {
        this["testDirect"] = () => console.log("Directly attached method called");
    }

}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const test = new B();
test.testInherit();
test.testDirect();
```

If we set a breakpoint after `test` is instantiated, we see the following:

[image]

As you can see, the `testDirect`-method is directly attached to `test`, while `testInherit` is multiple levels down.

---

I **personally** think this is bad practice:

- This might be true *now*, but it might not be true in the future. If V8 optimizes this internally, the current "optimization" might be significantly slower.
- The *claim* that it's an optimization holds no merit without profiling and sources.
- It's complicated to understand (see this question)
- Doing this can actually hurt performance. The linked article states as it's conclusion:

> don’t mess with prototypes

---

As for **modularity**: There is something to be said for having a clear base-class for all extension.

In a stricter language than JavaScript, such a class could offer specific methods that are only meant for extending, which are hidden from the public API for consumers. In this specific case however, `Logger` would have been fine on its own.

Comment: your answer makes me glad to have asked the question rather than just ignoring it! thanks!

Comment: Glad you kind-of confirmed [my conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936410/how-is-adding-a-new-class-with-prototype-methods-a-form-of-v8-optimization-in-js) on this ;) I like your visualization of the prototype chain traversal.